# Why is 50.22.53.71 hitting my localhost node.js in an attempt to find a php setup

Tags: security, php, localhost, node.js

I just created a new app using angular-fullstack yeoman generator, edited it a bit to my liking, and ran it with grunt on my localhost, and immediately upon starting up I get this flood of requests to paths that I haven't even defined.

Is this a hacking attempt? And if so, how does the hacker (human or bot) immediately know where my server is and when it came online? Note that I haven't made anything online, it's just a localhost setup and I'm merely connected to the internet. (Although my router does allow 80 port incoming.)

[Whois shows that the IP address belongs to a SoftLayer Technologies.](http://cqcounter.com/whois/ip/50.22.53.71.html) Never heard of it.

> Express server listening on 80, in development mode
>       GET / [200] | 127.0.0.1 (Chrome 31.0.1650)
>       GET /w00tw00t.at.blackhats.romanian.anti-sec:) [404] | 50.22.53.71 (Other)
>       GET /scripts/setup.php [404] | 50.22.53.71 (Other)
>       GET /admin/scripts/setup.php [404] | 50.22.53.71 (Other)
>       GET /admin/pma/scripts/setup.php [404] | 50.22.53.71 (Other)
>       GET /admin/phpmyadmin/scripts/setup.php [404] | 50.22.53.71 (Other)
>       GET /db/scripts/setup.php [404] | 50.22.53.71 (Other)
>       GET /dbadmin/scripts/setup.php [404] | 50.22.53.71 (Other)
>       GET /myadmin/scripts/setup.php [404] | 50.22.53.71 (Other)
>       GET /mysql/scripts/setup.php [404] | 50.22.53.71 (Other)
>       GET /mysqladmin/scripts/setup.php [404] | 50.22.53.71 (Other)
>       GET /typo3/phpmyadmin/scripts/setup.php [404] | 50.22.53.71 (Other)
>       GET /phpadmin/scripts/setup.php [404] | 50.22.53.71 (Other)
>       GET /phpMyAdmin/scripts/setup.php [404] | 50.22.53.71 (Other)
>       GET /phpmyadmin/scripts/setup.php [404] | 50.22.53.71 (Other)
>       GET /phpmyadmin1/scripts/setup.php [404] | 50.22.53.71 (Other)
>       GET /phpmyadmin2/scripts/setup.php [404] | 50.22.53.71 (Other)
>       GET /pma/scripts/setup.php [404] | 50.22.53.71 (Other)
>       GET /web/phpMyAdmin/scripts/setup.php [404] | 50.22.53.71 (Other)
>       GET /xampp/phpmyadmin/scripts/setup.php [404] | 50.22.53.71 (Other)
>       GET /web/scripts/setup.php [404] | 50.22.53.71 (Other)
>       GET /php-my-admin/scripts/setup.php [404] | 50.22.53.71 (Other)
>       GET /websql/scripts/setup.php [404] | 50.22.53.71 (Other)
>       GET /phpmyadmin/scripts/setup.php [404] | 50.22.53.71 (Other)
>       GET /phpMyAdmin/scripts/setup.php [404] | 50.22.53.71 (Other)
>       GET /phpMyAdmin-2/scripts/setup.php [404] | 50.22.53.71 (Other)
>       GET /php-my-admin/scripts/setup.php [404] | 50.22.53.71 (Other)
>       GET /phpMyAdmin-2.5.5/index.php [404] | 50.22.53.71 (Other)
>       GET /phpMyAdmin-2.5.5-pl1/index.php [404] | 50.22.53.71 (Other)
>       GET /phpMyAdmin/ [404] | 50.22.53.71 (Other)
>       GET /phpmyadmin/ [404] | 50.22.53.71 (Other)
>       GET /mysqladmin/ [404] | 50.22.53.71 (Other)

Comment: I don't know the answer, but does this area or company look familiar to you maybe? http://cqcounter.com/whois/ip/50.22.53.71.html

Comment: @FilipB.Vondrášek never heard of it.

Comment: Softlayer Technologies is only the Internet Services Provider, the IP itself seems to belong to certain ktools.net organization. I hope someone else will also contribute here, I myself would like to know what is going on.

Comment: That looks like a typical batch of hack probes.  I see stuff like that in http logs for live web sites everyday.  They scan IP's they find port 80 open and then they just throw a few 1000 attempts of known exploits at the site... if one of them gets the right reply the scanner forwards the info on to a human to further exploit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Is this a hacking attempt?*

Yes.

*And if so, how does the hacker (human or bot) immediately know where my server is and when it came online?*

You've hit the nail on the head, **you're online**. Just the act of being online exposes you to being scanned for vulnerabilities. They don't know you or that you put up a server. They do know the address ranges being used for servers and are actively scanning those addresses for vulnerabilities.

---

They're scanning for phpMyAdmin vulnerabilities or just to do a plain old login crack for phpMyAdmin or MySQL access.

This is one reason you run phpMyAdmin behind cPanel and another reason why you run MySQL as localhost and don't expose it to open web access.

Both can be used to muck with your databases for anything from inserting iframes to downright theft of data.

Just because the address comes from SoftLayer (SoftLayer is one of the largest server farm operations on the planet) doesn't mean much, except the attack is being relayed off a compromised server that they host.

Every server out there on the net sees these. If they're too persistent, one way of handling it is to take a common match in the requests and 403 it in your .htaccess with mod_alias and a RedirectMatch line.

And at the moment, you should be seeing a lot of wp-admin and fckeditor crack attempts for the latest WordPress trackback vulnerability as well.

Comment: Found this answer intresting, could you elaborate more on the htaccess lines, mod_alias and Redirect Match, what lines would you put and how do they work?